# Running Python code in a docker container using PyCharm

Tags: python, docker, pycharm, mapping

I'd like to run my project in a Docker container using PyCharm. I had no issue doing that using the default PyCharm options, but when I wanted to have my PyCharm project folder mapped to the /app folder on the Docker container I started to keep stuck with files not found. And actually, the /app folder on the Docker container is empty (checked using the os package in Python by using the Python console after PyCharm starts the container).

- I have a Docker image with WORKDIR set to /app
- I have created a PyCharm environment with no path mapping
- I have my PyCharm project on my host machine (Mac) at /User/myuser/project/
- I'd like to map the folder /User/myuser/project/ on the host to /app on the guest and then run the code from there
- You can find PyCharm Run Configuration attached as image
  [image]

Comment: I believe you need to mount/copy your local project to `/app` in `Dockerfile`. PyCharm won't do it itself just because you have a path mapping defined in the run configuration.

Comment: So what's a path mapping in PyCharm?

Comment: To let PyCharm know where to find your code inside the container instead of `/opt/project`.